# How do I reach the scenic spot on top of the Ossuaire?

Tags: the-saboteur

I have tried for a long time to get onto the Ossuaire in *The Saboteur*, but I don't find any place to climb it. The yellow lights have not been helpful either. How do I reach the scenic spot?

**TL;DR: There is none.**

Comment: is the mission called *Behind The Convent Gate*?

Comment: @Taz: yes, I think so.

Comment: I have posted the solution to the mission and also to help find all the *Scenic Spots* since L'Ossusaire seems to not have one all others are included. As your questions asks about both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no scenic spot on top of the Ossuaire. (I was misled by the existence of yellow lights, and I thought that every major building in the game has a scenic spot on top of it, because the others do, and I had not bought the map of targets yet.)

Answer (score 2):

Below is the walk-through for the mission that involves L'Ossusaire. However, in this mission it is not a requirement to be on the roof. Also included is steps to obtain all the diffecult *Scenic Spots*.

### Behind The Convent Gate (optional mission)

Talk with Wilcox in the church to start this mission.  He wants you to blow up 
an old abbey.

> Objective: Go To L'Ossusaire

Drive to L'Ossuaire, its on the other side of the map east of Lorainne.

> Objective: Destroy L'Ossusaire

You need to destroy several targets marked around the abbey.  You'll want to 
  take out the guy in the tower by the gate to grab his uniform, makes sneaking 
  around inside the abbey easier.Blow up each terminal, and don't forget to collect the post card on the floor behind the right side machine gun before you blow that radio station.

- Nazi Radar Emplacement (x3)
- Nazi Radio Tower       (x6)
- Nazi radio Controls    (x5)

  When all the targets are destroyed you'll complete the mission.

Taken from [here.](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/sg/saboteur.txt)

---

However, to find all the Scenic Spots, the below is how to get to them.

There are hundreds of freeplay objectives around the map to destroy.  These 
range from searchlights to AA Guns.  For each one destroyed you will be paid a 
small amount of contraband.  Contraband is required to buy weapons and 
ammunition.  You need to buy maps to show you where all the targets are.

You can complete the free play objectives at anytime even during missions.

## 06.01 - Scenic Spots

I have listed how to get some of the scenic spots that I found tricky to get 
and how to get to them.  The way you get up them on each building look for the 
yellow lights they usually mark the way.

### Scenic Spots (Paris 1)

1) Top of building in La Halles
   You need to climb up to the western side. On the triangle roof face south 
   and run jump up the wall.  Alternatively just climb the ladder around the 
   corner.  You can climb to the top easily from here.

2) Top of circular building in La Halles
   When you get the one on the bigger building use the wire to slide across to 
   the other.

3) top of building in La Bourse
   Climb up the drainpipe in the southeast corner of the building.  About 
   halfway up Jump off onto the platforms to the left.  Face south and running 
   jump away from the building and you'll grab some planks.  Pull yourself up.
   Go along planks and up the ladder.  Jump up to the next set of planks.
   Grab the ledge at the top of the building pull yourself up twice and you'll 
   be on the roof.

4) Building In Opera District
   Use the wire on the building to the west to slide over.  Move right 
   slightly then climb up.  Face away from the building jump away from the 
   building then quickly back and you'll be on the roof.  This bit can be 
   tricky but once you've done it then it plain sailing.

### Saarbrucken

1) Climb the pipe near the door up to the roof

### Champagne Ardenne

1) Climb on top of house and face tower.  Jump at the window on the tower and 
   climb up.

### Le Harve

1) Top Of Lighthouse - use the windows to head up in an clockwise circle.
2) Top of castle - climb up inner bell tower in courtyard in the middle of the 
   castle in the far north west of the map.  Once inside the bell tower climb 
   up the inside wall in the north east of the tower to get to the top.

### Paris 2

1) South of Champs Elysees, climb up the ladder on the south west corner of 
   the "D" shaped building.  Jump up and shimmy right and you should be able 
   to climb up to the walkway on your right.  Climb up the small ladder again 
   and its near the guard tower.

2) South of Champs Elysees, use zipline from roof of 2 above.  Climb one of 
   the square structure on the corner of the building and running jump 
   towards the arch.  You should be able to run up to the platform and climb up.

3) Trocadero - use the scaffolding and windows to climb to the roof.  Ascend 
   a big ladder then turn around and climb a massive drainpipe.  Jump across 
   to ledge then climb up.

4) "A" shaped building south of opera district text.  Approach from the north 
    and you should be able to climb the outside easily.  Once on roof head to 
    the spot in the centre of the building.

5) Big coliseum style building just south of the Gare Saint Lazarre.  Look 
   for the wire from the building to the west.  Climb that building and cross 
   the wire.  Drop and press right to grab the walkway and then pull yourself 
   up.  Jump up to the ladder and you're on the roof.

6) Isle De La Cite (east building) - Grab a Nazi uniform and swim in from Paris 
   zone 3.  Climb up the ladder and enter the area.  Go to the north side of 
   the big building.  Climb up the small scaffolding then onto the pointed roof.
   Ascend the drainpipe and climb up onto a platform before climbing up another 
   drainpipe.  Pull yourself up to the roof and you're there.

7) Gare Saint Lazarre - on the building behind is a connecting walkway you 
   need to use that to cross to the building with the spot.  Use the small 
   ledges along the station building.  The last jump up can be tricky you 
   have to do a running jump up the building then press right to grab the 
   ledge near the walkway.  Pull yourself up on the roof and its easy from here.

### Paris 3

1) Isle De La Cite (west building) - along the inside northern wall is some 
   scaffolding, use this to climb up.  Then climb the wall and its on the roof.

2) Isle De La Cite (west building) - along the outside corner of the wall there 
   is a row of lights.  Climb up the post on the corner and up to the ledge.
   Pull yourself up then climb up the window and the wall to the roof.  Climb 
   up the small scaffolding on the roof to the scenic spot.

3) Montparnasse far north near check point.  Go around the back of the building 
   and climb up the door in the bit sticking out.  Climb onto to the main 
   building and shimmer left or right to the corner then pull yourself up.

4) Montparnasse far north near check point.  Climb up the build building.
   Locate the scaffolding on the west side of the building.  Climb up the 
   first short ladder.  Make your way up the scaffolding to the spot on the 
   top of the building.

5) Top of building near Paris Saint Germain.  Use the ladder on the south side 
   of building to get to the first roof.  Head west and climb up the next 
   ladder.  Go to the north side of the building and there is another ladder 
   up to the next roof.  Then there is a final set of scaffolding to climb.
   Jump up and pull yourself up inside the dome.

6) Top of the Eiffel Tower.  You need to use the lift to get to the first level.
   A second lift will take you to the next level.  You then need to use the 
   stairs and ladders to get to the summit.

7) Church north of Saint Germain.  Climb up the low roof of the north side.
   Go all the way around to the south side and climb up on the outcropping 
   stone.  Pull yourself up to the roof.  Follow the roof to the scaffolding 
   and climb the ladder.  Jump to the next platform with a ladder up and climb 
   it.

8) Big building south west of Latin quarter.  Climb up the scaffolding on the 
   south side of building.  Jump to the drainpipe and pull yourself up.
   Shimmer right along ledge and pull yourself up.  Climb ladder to roof.  Now 
   climb up the ladder by the scaffolding in front of you.  Then climb up the 
   next set of scaffolding you see.  Climb up to the ledge and pull yourself 
   up.  Follow the walkway left.  Climb the ladder to the very big gun at the 
   top. Climb up little ladder to get on the gun.  Climb up the ladder at the 
   side of the gun.  Climb up the next two ladders to the spot.

9) Building north east of Eiffel Tower.  Look on the east side of the building 
   for some lights and climb up the windows to the roof.  Running jump east to 
   the planks opposite.  Follow the ledge around to the scaffolding and climb 
   the ladder.  Climb up to the next level then use the window to get to the 
   plank in the corner of the building.  Do a running jump up the wall then 
   pull yourself up onto the roof.  Look for the window with the wooden ramp 
   in front.  Climb onto the ledge then use the left hand side of the window 
   to climb up.  Grab the top of the window.  Shimmer across to the ladder and 
   climb up.  Then jump up and climb up the remaining wall to get to the top 
   of the building.  Spot is on the south side.

10) Directly east of Eiffel Tower.  On the south side of the building you'll 
    see a light.  You should be able to climb up the middle of the door.
    Shimmy left and pull yourself up.  Climb up the wall to the left and pull 
    yourself up onto the wooden walkway.  Make your way to the one to the west.
    Drop down and cling to the ledge.  Jump and shimmy around the stone then 
    pull yourself up to the next wooden walkway.  Then climb to the next 
    wooden walkway and up onto the roof.  You should see the spot to the east 
    along the roof.

11) This in on the big ferris wheel in the fairground.  You can use the outer 
    leg to run up to the centre of the ferris wheel.  Jump out and grab one of 
    the spokes of the wheel.  Climb and pull yourself up until you can't go any 
    higher.  Then you can make your way along the edge other wheel so you can 
    make your way up to the top.  When you get there hang on the outside and 
    jump up and you'll pull yourself level with the final spot inside the car.

Taken from  [here.](http://www.cheatbook.de/wfiles/saboteurpc.htm)

Comment: It's called Ossuaire, not Ossusaire (it's French for Ossuary) and the scenic spot on top of it is not in the guide, which I found with Google myself ...

Comment: @FelixDombek post your answer up for others.

Comment: My answer? There is no answer, I can't find any information about this scenic spot online, but I think there is one because (1) there is one on basically every special building in the game, (2) there are yellow lights marking the way up. I just don't see where to start! The only thing I can imagine is that one could use a sniper tower near the Ossuary to jump on it, but I took that tower down before I noticed the yellow lights. However, all other scenic spots in the game are always reachable (the way up can't be destroyed), so I don't really believe that this one isn't.